# Brun’s constant and irrational numbers

Tags: irrational-numbers, constants, prime-gaps, twin-primes

It is trivial that if there are finitely many twin primes then Brun’s constant must be a rational number. And GammaTester (below) has offered an example of an infinite series that converges to a rational number.

My question is, even if there are infinitely many twin primes, then how is it possible for Brun's constant to be (potentially) irrational, since it is an infinite always-positive sum of always-rational numbers? How can such a sum converge on an irrational number?

Comment: An infinite sum of (non-zero) rationals can be rational, e.g. $\sum 2^{-n}$

Comment: OK, thanks. But I'm going to edit the OP to a slightly different question: if each term of an always-positive series such Brun's is rational - then how i it possible for the sum to converge on an irrational number?

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward Every (positive) irrational can be represented as an infinite sum of (positive) rational numbers. Think decimals.

Comment: OK, feeling totally dumb just now! Of course correct and blindingly obvious. How do I mark this answered?